# My customizable welcome channel feature for my Discord bot isn't working, it looks like a problem with MongoDB but I'm unable to figure it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

My customizable welcome channel feature for my Discord bot isn't working. I use MongoDB so I can make it customizable per-server.

There are 3 relevant files: `welcome.js` (my schema file), `guildMemberAdd.js` (my event file) and `setwelcome.js` (the command I use to set the welcome channel.)

The `welcome.js` file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  welcomeChannelId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  welcomeText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('welcome', schema);
```

The `guildMemberAdd.js` file:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const schema = require('../models/welcome.js')

const welcomeData = {}

module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    async execute(member) {
        const g = member.guild;
        const ms = require('ms');
        const timeSpan = ms('10 days');

        //Alt detection
        const createdAt = new Date(member.user.createdAt).getTime();
        const difference = Date.now() - createdAt;

        if (difference < timeSpan) {
            member.send('Bye, alt.');
            member.ban({ reason: 'This is an alt.' });
        }

        //Welcome Users
    
    let data = welcomeData[member.guild.id]
    if (!data) {
      const results = await schema.find({
        _id: member.guild.id
      })
      if (!results) {
        return
      }

      const { welcomeChannelId, welcomeText } = results
      const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId)
      data = welcomeData[member.guild.id] = [channel, welcomeText]
    }

    data[0].send({
      content: data[1].replace(/@/g, `<@${member.id}>`)
    })


    },
};
```

The `setwelcome.js` file

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const schema = require('../../models/welcome.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'setwelcome',
    description: 'Sets the welcome message for the server.',
  options: [{
    name: 'channel',
    description: 'The channel to set as the welcome channel.',
    type: 'CHANNEL',
    required: true
  },
  {
    name: 'message',
    description: 'The welcome message.',
    type: 'STRING',
    required: true
  }],
    async execute(interaction) {
        const channel = await interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
    const message = await interaction.options.getString('message')

    if (
            channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT' &&
            channel.type !== 'GUILD_NEWS' &&
            channel.type !== 'GUILD_NEWS_THREAD' &&
            channel.type !== 'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD' &&
            channel.type !== 'GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD'
        )
            return interaction.reply('That is not a valid channel type.');


    await schema.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: interaction.guild.id,
    },
    {
      _id: interaction.guild.id,
      welcomeChannelId: channel.id,
      welcomeText: message   
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    })

    await interaction.reply(`Welcome channel is set to ${channel} and welcome message is set to \`${message}\`.`)
    },
};
```

When a new member joins the guild, it throws this error:

```
 /home/runner/MultiBot/events/guildMemberAdd.js:38
 data[0].send({
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/MultiBot/events/guildMemberAdd.js:38:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Please help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from posting a lot of code or the complete error message, try to be more specific so we can help you better and faster.

Comment: Can you console.log(data)

Comment: @Zero
`console.log(data)`
`console.log(welcomeData[member.guild.id])`

I inserted these lines of code just above the `data[0].send` line, and it logs

`[ undefined, undefined ]`
`[ undefined, undefined ]`

Comment: Well of course then it is pretty clear that it is unable to push the data itself so you might wanna debug and check what's going on in your actual mongoose connection, why exactly is the data `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `const { welcomeChannelId, welcomeText } = results` with `const { welcomeChannelId, welcomeText } = results[0]` as results is an array

or

use `const results = await schema.findOne({ _id: member.guild.id })`
to have `results` be only one object

Answer (score 0):

This means that `message` is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish). Make sure the argument is actually there. There are 3 ways:

1. Making the slash command options **required** (recommended)
2. Returning early if the argument is not found

```js
if (!message) return; //after the 'message' declaration
```

3. Setting a default value, this uses the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) (the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) will also suffice)

```js
const message = await interaction.options.getString('message') || "Welcome to the server!"
```

Comment: But both `channel` and `message` ARE required, then why the error?

Comment: Are you setting the label correctly?

Comment: wdym by "label"?

Comment: can you show how you create the slash commands instead of the schema please?

Comment: I have provided the `setwelcome.js` file, which is my slash cmd file

Comment: try console logging `message` and tell me what it logs

Comment: It logs what I provide in the cmd options
I provided `Hi, @!` and it logged `Hi, @!`

Comment: Weird, that error shouldn't be thrown if that's the value of `message`

Comment: I have edited my code to have the badword and welcome schemas separate, and also updated the question. Now it throws a different error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because data is an array/object and doesn't have a send method. You would need to find the channel before sending it with something like

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(welcomeChannelId);
```

Comment: But I did do that
I fetched the channel using the id and stored the _channel_ in `data[0]`

Comment: Yes, but you can't send to a string. you need to fetch the channel in discord.js to be able to send to it